# How to create a GroupBy function that is better aligned with relational algebra?

Tags: data, dataset, associations, sets

I want a GroupBy function that behaves more in alignment with [relational algebra principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra).
I can get what I want if I do it in 2 steps:

Preparation:

```
data = {<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2, "C" -> 10|>, <|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2, 
    "C" -> 20|>, <|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 3, "C" -> 30|>, <|"A" -> 2, 
    "B" -> 4, "C" -> 40|>, <|"A" -> 2, "B" -> 4, "C" -> 50|>};

ds = Dataset[data];
```

Step 1:

```
groupedData = ds[GroupBy[{#A, #B} &]];
```

Step 2:

```
nestedRelationDataset = 
 Dataset@
  KeyValueMap[
   Function[{key, value}, <|"A" -> key[[1]], "B" -> key[[2]], 
     "Nested" -> value|>], groupedData]
```

Output:

```
Dataset[{<|A->1,B->2,Nested->{<|A->1,B->2,C->10|>,<|A->1,B->2,C->20|>}|>,<|A->1,B->3,Nested->{<|A->1,B->3,C->30|>}|>,<|A->2,B->4,Nested->{<|A->2,B->4,C->40|>,<|A->2,B->4,C->50|>}|>}]
```

But when I try to combine them, result is nonsensical:

```
relationalGroupBy[ds_Dataset, groupCols_List] := 
 Module[{groupedData, nestedRelationDataset},
  groupedData = ds[GroupBy[groupCols]];
  nestedRelationDataset = 
   Dataset@
    KeyValueMap[
     Function[{key, value}, 
      Association[groupCols -> key, "Nested" -> value]], 
     groupedData];
  nestedRelationDataset]
```

Single Call:

```
relationalGroupBy[ds, {"A", "B"}]
```

Output:

```
Dataset[{<|{A,B}->A(<|A->1,B->2,C->10|>),Nested-><|B(<|A->1,B->2,C->10|>)->{<|A->1,B->2,C->10|>}|>|>,<|{A,B}->A(<|A->1,B->2,C->20|>),Nested-><|B(<|A->1,B->2,C->20|>)->{<|A->1,B->2,C->20|>}|>|>,<|{A,B}->A(<|A->1,B->3,C->30|>),Nested-><|B(<|A->1,B->3,C->30|>)->{<|A->1,B->3,C->30|>}|>|>,<|{A,B}->A(<|A->2,B->4,C->40|>),Nested-><|B(<|A->2,B->4,C->40|>)->{<|A->2,B->4,C->40|>}|>|>,<|{A,B}->A(<|A->2,B->4,C->50|>),Nested-><|B(<|A->2,B->4,C->50|>)->{<|A->2,B->4,C->50|>}|>|>}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Update**. This:

```
relationalGroupBy[ds_Dataset, grouper_Function, groupCols_List] := 
 Module[{groupedData, nestedRelationDataset}, 
  groupedData = ds[GroupBy[grouper]];
  nestedRelationDataset = 
   Dataset@
    KeyValueMap[
     Function[{key, value}, 
      Association[groupCols -> key, "Nested" -> value]], 
     groupedData];
  nestedRelationDataset]
```

with this:

```
relationalGroupBy[ds, {#A, #B} &, {"A", "B"}]
```

fails too:

```
Dataset[{<|{A,B}->{1,2},Nested->{<|A->1,B->2,C->10|>,<|A->1,B->2,C->20|>}|>,<|{A,B}->{1,3},Nested->{<|A->1,B->3,C->30|>}|>,<|{A,B}->{2,4},Nested->{<|A->2,B->4,C->40|>,<|A->2,B->4,C->50|>}|>}]
```

Comment: look at `ds[GroupBy[{"A", "B"}]]`

Comment: Thanks for commenting @lericr, but I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: What I mean is that `ds[GroupBy[{"A", "B"}]]` gives a very different result than `ds[GroupBy[{#A, #B} &]]`. In your step-by-step approach you had `groupedData = ds[GroupBy[{#A, #B} &]]`, but in your single call you had `relationalGroupBy[ds, {"A", "B"}]`. In `relationalGroupBy` you have `groupedData = ds[GroupBy[groupCols]]`, so that `groupCols` will be the string version, not the function version.

Comment: I see, indeed, not the same, but I cannot find a way to make it work...

Comment: At this point I'd be happy even if I had to use anugly and redundant extra parameter: `relationalGroupBy[ds, {#A, #B} &,  {"A", "B"}]` but try as I might, that also does not seem to work. I guess this kind of code requires of way more advanced knowledge of Mathematica syntax that I can manage today

Comment: I guess I'm struggling with understanding what you want to do with this structure. What you've said is your desired result looks awkward to me. Nevertheless, one thing you might try is creating an aggregate key. Something like this: `ds[All, <|"Key" -> <|"A" -> #A, "B" -> #B|>, "Val" -> #|> &]`. Then you can do your grouping with `GroupBy["Key"]`

Comment: So, putting it all together: `ds[All, <|"Key" -> <|"A" -> #A, "B" -> #B|>, "Val" -> #|> &][GroupBy["Key"], All, "Val"]` will get you close to what you had, but it might (depending on your use case) actually be easier to work with (though the display form will look slightly more awkward).

Comment: Oh, and for whatever it's worth, you can turn a list of string-keys into a function like this: `Function[Evaluate[Slot /@ {"A","B"}]]`. So, in your `relationalGroupBy` function you could use this line: `groupedData = ds[GroupBy[Function[Evaluate[Slot /@ groupCols]]]]`

Comment: "I guess I'm struggling with understanding what you want to do with this structure" In short, relational algebra has this closure property that allows expressions to be nested, just as in arithmetic. Mathematica's GroupBy breaks that by not returning a well formed DataSet when applied to a dataset: it returns columns without headers so, after GroupBy you cannot for example do a JoinAcross over keys because, you no longer columns with keys. This is my approach to fixing that shortcoming.

Comment: What I was hinting at was...maybe there's a better way to solve your problem. While nesting in the relational model can be done in a rigorous way, what you're doing looks like a pretty blatant violation of the relational model (I can't say that with certainty since I don't know your semantics, but it's very suspicious). I can't think of any query that is made easier with your nested structure than without. So it'd be interesting to know what queries you're hoping to facilitate. I'm basically just offering to help you get to your end result. But if what you have now makes you happy, then great.

Comment: Improvements are welcome. I am surprised you think it is a blatant violation of relational model. It is actually as close at I think I can get to C.J. Date Database in Depth Chapter 5 GROUP recommendation on https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/database-in-depth/0596100124/ch05.html#databaseid-CHP-5-SECT-5. I think picture there looks very close to the output of the function I am trying to build (if the other link does not work, this might: https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/sql-and-relational/9781449319724/ch07s10.html ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144795/discussion-between-lericr-and-luxspes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`RightComposition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html). Well, you can also use [`Composition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) but I prefer the former for [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) which is what you are using in [`Dataset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html).

Your set of functions can work with a few tweaks.

```
ClearAll[relationalGroupBy]
relationalGroupBy[ds_Dataset, groupCols_List] :=
 ds[
  GroupBy[Evaluate[Slot /@ groupCols] &]/*
   KeyValueMap[{Sequence @@ Thread[groupCols -> #], "Nested" -> #2} &]/*
   Map[Association]
  ]
```

Then with `ds` as in OP.

```
relationalGroupBy[ds, {"A", "B"}] // Normal
```

> ```
> { <|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2, 
>    "Nested" -> {<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2, "C" -> 10|>, <|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 2, "C" -> 20|>}|>
>  ,<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 3, 
>    "Nested" -> {<|"A" -> 1, "B" -> 3, "C" -> 30|>}|>
>  ,<|"A" -> 2, "B" -> 4, 
>   "Nested" -> {<|"A" -> 2, "B" -> 4, "C" -> 40|>, <|"A" -> 2, "B" -> 4, "C" -> 50|>}|> }
> ```

I used [`Postfix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Postfix.html) and [`Normal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) to unpack the `Dataset` for the post.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I hope one day i will understand what you did

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bit self-serving, but based on the comments I think there are some relevant alternatives to explore. The OP, in a comment, linked to a grouping operator described by C.J. Date. However, Date's grouping operator doesn't repeat all of the original columns within the relations that become the values in the new group column. I think this is a reasonable semantic, because it allows futher "natural" operations on these relational values that the inclusion of the original columns would impede. In effect, we're picking a key for the new relation, and having that key be duplicated in the grouped value (a relation itself) would usually constitute a functional dependency (I mean, maybe the semantic context would make this okay, but I think in normal circumstances this would end up being denormalized).

With that preamble, here is an implementation that I think is closer to the spirit of Date's grouping operator:

```
groupRelationally[ds_Dataset, cols_List] :=
  With[
    {keyGroup = Thread[cols -> (Slot /@ cols)]},
    ds[All, <|keyGroup -> {"Group" -> KeyDrop[#, cols]}|> &][Merge[Identity]][KeyValueMap[<|#1, Merge[Identity][#2]|> &]]]
```

Someone with more proficienty with Dataset might be able to simplify this. Also, "Group" is a bit lazy, but I didn't want to obfuscate the code just to create a better column name. Anyawy, let's compare this with the OP's original expectation:

**original expectation**

```
relationalGroupBy[ds, {"A", "B"}]
```

[image]

**variant aligned with Date's grouping operator**

```
groupRelationally[ds, {"A", "B"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Thank! One thing I realized, however, after re-reading those C.J. Date chapters is that there are 2 operators Group and GroupBy (the latter being the one available in SQL). In GroupBy you specify the columns that will not be nested. In Group, you specificy the columns to nest. (So, to be fully Date operator compliant, you either have to change the name of your function to "groupByRelationally", on reverse its behavior)

Comment: lol. That's how I did it originally (the reverse behavior), and then I decided to change it when I posted so that it matched the signature of your method. But yes, you are right.